# Write mySQL to get a sequence

Tags: mysql

I need to get the sequence of win or lost for a specific sport team. For example:

TABLE : RESULTS

```
teamid    win  eventdate
======    ===  =========
1         0    26/01/2014
1         0    25/01/2014
2         1    26/01/2014
1         0    24/01/2014 
1         1    21/01/2014
```

It should return teamid 1 has a sequence of 3 lost. But how in sql can I do that?

Comment: So what if team 1 had a sequence of 3 losses, followed by 4 wins, followed by 2 losses; and team 2 had a sequence of 7 wins and 8 losses?  What result would you expect?

Comment: Should be order by eventdate DESC

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  At all.

Comment: Team 1 has a sequence of 2 losses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support analytic functions, but one way of counting sequential wins/losses is via [user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html):

```
SELECT   @seq    := IF(@teamid<=>teamid AND @win<=>win,@seq,0)+1 seq,
         @teamid := teamid teamid,
         @win    := win win
FROM     RESULTS, (SELECT @teamid:=NULL, @win:=NULL) init
ORDER BY teamid, STR_TO_DATE(eventdate, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

This query can be used as a basis for performing further analysis.  For example, to obtain the longest streaks (both winning and losing) by team:

```
SELECT teamid, win, MAX(seq) FROM (
  SELECT   @seq    := IF(@teamid<=>teamid AND @win<=>win,@seq,0)+1 seq,
           @teamid := teamid teamid,
           @win    := win win
  FROM     RESULTS, (SELECT @teamid:=NULL, @win:=NULL) init
  ORDER BY teamid, STR_TO_DATE(eventdate, '%d/%m/%Y')
) t GROUP BY teamid, win
```